# jQuery Animation : changing an animation parameter mid-animation

Tags: jquery, animation

Suppose you had a long animation where you were changing the `width`:

```
var myTargetWidth = 500;
$(el).animate( { "width" : myTargetWidth }, 5000 );
```

The animation is asynchronous so your code continues . . .
a couple seconds later you decide to change the target `width` to `300` . . .
the animation is still running at this point . . .

How would I change targetWidth to a different value on the running animation?

Comment: have you tried just changing myTargetWidth mid animation to see what happens? I reckon it won't do anything because internally it will have been stored in which case you will have to see if you can decipher the jQuery source to see how to access that parameter mid-flow.

Comment: Yes, you should accept an answer as correct if it is! You have many open questions @eeejay

Comment: Yes eeejay... mark answers that work for you as correct that is the whole point of this site. Also look at the answe that mentions step (not .stop)... its almost certainly a better fit for your question than the .stop answers

Comment: Hey @eeejay You may accept any of the answers! Or is it that none of them solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use the `step` function mentioned in the jQuery `animate` function ([API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/))
to check a condition while the animation is running.

Example JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GweLA/13/

**JS**

```
var myTargetWidth = 500;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sample').animate( { "width" : myTargetWidth },{
        duration : 5000,      
        step: function(now, fx) {
            if($(this).width() > 200){
              myTargetWidth = 300;
              $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : myTargetWidth },1000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.sample{
    width:20px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#cccccc;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sample">
   width is supposed to be animated till 500 but it stops at 300
</div>
```

---

**Solution 2:**

After some research I found that we can modify the `start` and `end` properties of `fx` parameter passed to the step function to control the animation. This kind of smoothens the animation, but not a very tidy way of doing it though.

Example JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GweLA/57/

**JS**

```
var myTargetWidth = 500;
var isExecuted = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sample').animate( { "width" : myTargetWidth },{
        duration : 5000,
        queue : false,
        step: function(now, fx) {
                 //So that fx.start and fx.end is set only once                
                if($(this).width() > 200 && $(this).width() < 203){
                    if(!isExecuted){
                        fx.start = now-65;
                        fx.end = 300;
                    }
                    isExecuted = true;
                }
              }
    });
});
```

Comment: nice. I thought it would be difficult. Nice answer and +1 for .step

Comment: @Crispwind, when it hits 200, there is a bit of a "bump" as it stops the current animation and starts the new animation headed for the new value of 300.  Is there a way instead, to modify the running animation and changing its target CSS so that you do not have to stop and restart the animation?

Comment: @eeejay > I have added an alternate solution. It not perfect though!

Comment: 4 years later, just wanted to say that the second solution is ingenius! Haven't seen it elsewhere either (I guess this is not a really common problem, though)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of **[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)** - To stop the animation.

**[:animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)** selector - Which checks if the current element is being animated..

Try this

**HTML**

```
​<div class="a">

​</div>

​<button id="check">Check Animation </button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Javascript**

```
var myTargetWidth = 300;
var $el = $('.a')
$el.animate({
    "width": myTargetWidth
}, 5000);

$('#check').on('click', function() {
    var newHeight = 300;
    if ($('.a:animated')) {
        $el.stop().animate({
            "height": newHeight
        }, 5000);
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Mv4VF/)**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at effects.js in jquery github you will have problems changing the variable after assignment

Source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js

NOTE: Note the assigment and object creation in .animate to Animation (the work horse)

```
animate: function( prop, speed, easing, callback ) {
    var empty = jQuery.isEmptyObject( prop ),
    optall = jQuery.speed( speed, easing, callback ),
    doAnimation = function() {
        // Operate on a copy of prop so per-property easing won't be lost
        var anim = Animation( this, jQuery.extend( {}, prop ), optall );

        // Empty animations resolve immediately
        if ( empty ) {
           anim.stop( true );
        }
    };

return empty || optall.queue === false ?
this.each( doAnimation ) :
this.queue( optall.queue, doAnimation );
}
```

//Animate in effects.js

```
function Animation( elem, properties, options ) {
    var result,
        index = 0,
        length = animationPrefilters.length,
        deferred = jQuery.Deferred().always( function() {
            // don't match elem in the :animated selector
            delete tick.elem;
        }),
        tick = function() {
            var currentTime = fxNow || createFxNow(),
                remaining = Math.max( 0, animation.startTime + animation.duration - currentTime ),
                // archaic crash bug won't allow us to use 1 - ( 0.5 || 0 ) (#12497)
                temp = remaining / animation.duration || 0,
                percent = 1 - temp,
                index = 0,
                length = animation.tweens.length;

            for ( ; index < length ; index++ ) {
                animation.tweens[ index ].run( percent );
            }

            deferred.notifyWith( elem, [ animation, percent, remaining ]);

            if ( percent < 1 && length ) {
                return remaining;
            } else {
                deferred.resolveWith( elem, [ animation ] );
                return false;
            }
        },
        animation = deferred.promise({
            elem: elem,
            props: jQuery.extend( {}, properties ),
            opts: jQuery.extend( true, { specialEasing: {} }, options ),
            originalProperties: properties,
            originalOptions: options,
            startTime: fxNow || createFxNow(),
            duration: options.duration,
            tweens: [],
            createTween: function( prop, end ) {
                var tween = jQuery.Tween( elem, animation.opts, prop, end,
                        animation.opts.specialEasing[ prop ] || animation.opts.easing );
                animation.tweens.push( tween );
                return tween;
            },
            stop: function( gotoEnd ) {
                var index = 0,
                    // if we are going to the end, we want to run all the tweens
                    // otherwise we skip this part
                    length = gotoEnd ? animation.tweens.length : 0;

                for ( ; index < length ; index++ ) {
                    animation.tweens[ index ].run( 1 );
                }

                // resolve when we played the last frame
                // otherwise, reject
                if ( gotoEnd ) {
                    deferred.resolveWith( elem, [ animation, gotoEnd ] );
                } else {
                    deferred.rejectWith( elem, [ animation, gotoEnd ] );
                }
                return this;
            }
        }),
        props = animation.props;

    propFilter( props, animation.opts.specialEasing );

    for ( ; index < length ; index++ ) {
        result = animationPrefilters[ index ].call( animation, elem, props, animation.opts );
        if ( result ) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    createTweens( animation, props );

    if ( jQuery.isFunction( animation.opts.start ) ) {
        animation.opts.start.call( elem, animation );
    }

    jQuery.fx.timer(
        jQuery.extend( tick, {
            anim: animation,
            queue: animation.opts.queue,
            elem: elem
        })
    );

    // attach callbacks from options
    return animation.progress( animation.opts.progress )
        .done( animation.opts.done, animation.opts.complete )
        .fail( animation.opts.fail )
        .always( animation.opts.always );
}
```

As a result I think you will have to .stop and requeue the animation with the changed variable as you have little hope of accessing any of the variables in the closure (someone correct me please)

Answer (score 0):

I have added an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3ZcQ/

Try clicking the 'click here' element mid animation...

I use the `clearQueue()` and `stop()` functions.

CSS
    #block { width:100px; height: 100px; background: red; }​

HTML

```
<p>
  <a id="clickme">Click here</a>
</p>
```

jQUERY

```
$('#clickme').not('.again').on('mouseup',function() {
  $(this).addClass('again');
  $('#block').animate({
    width: '400'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

$('.again').live('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('again');
 $('#block').clearQueue().animate({
    width: '200',
  }, 500, function() {
     $('#block').stop(true, false);
  });
});​
<div id="block" />​
```